# How can we limit elasticdump with searchBody option as it seems not to be working with provided timestamp query

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-plugin, elk

I want to extract some logs from ES Cluster to a file for a specific period (as they are in millions)

I've tried https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump with its **--searchBody** option as below:

```
elasticdump --input="some.endpoint" --output="somelocation/my_index.json" --ignoreType='mapping,settings,template' --limit 2000 -- --searchBody='{"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":[{"field":"@timestamp","format":"date_time"}],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"format":"strict_date_optional_time","gte":"2019-12-17T12:00:00.000Z","lte":"2019-12-17T12:00:15.000Z"}}}],"filter":[{"match_all":{}}],"should":[],"must_not":[]}}}'
```

It does generate a file with logs though it seems like it is not considering the **--searchBody** query as the logs are starting from **"@timestamp":"2019-12-03T05:09:46.902+0000"** and goes to like **infinity** (had to manually stop the process)

Also tried with `--debug` and got the same
Reference

```
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT | starting dump
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT [debug] | discovered elasticsearch input major version: 7
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT | got 100 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination file, wrote 100
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT [debug] | scrollRequest: {"uri":"my.endpoint/_search/scroll","method":"POST","body":"{\"scroll\":\"10m\",\"scroll_id\":\"DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoVgAAAAAAAIaUFnBhbjFwTWVlUmx5dU5XTU5YNGJMMEEAAAAAAACg_BZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpUWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJz-FmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg-hZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpYWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0AFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg-xZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpcWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJz_FmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACdAhZhYlhpcFhRTlIxaUdNWU92X09ycGp3AAAAAAAAhpgWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0BFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg_RZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpkWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAIaaFnBhbjFwTWVlUmx5dU5XTU5YNGJMMEEAAAAAAACg_hZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpsWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0DFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg_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\"}"}
Thu, 19 Dec 2019 12:34:43 GMT [debug] | body: "{\"_scroll_id\":\"DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoVgAAAAAAAIaUFnBhbjFwTWVlUmx5dU5XTU5YNGJMMEEAAAAAAACg_BZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpUWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJz-FmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg-hZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpYWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0AFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg-xZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpcWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJz_FmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACdAhZhYlhpcFhRTlIxaUdNWU92X09ycGp3AAAAAAAAhpgWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0BFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg_RZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpkWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAIaaFnBhbjFwTWVlUmx5dU5XTU5YNGJMMEEAAAAAAACg_hZBOHVNTTN4R1NoT2RpRmpwODA0YUZRAAAAAAAAhpsWcGFuMXBNZWVSbHl1TldNTlg0YkwwQQAAAAAAAJ0DFmFiWGlwWFFOUjFpR01ZT3ZfT3JwancAAAAAAACg_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\",\"took\":1,\"timed_out\":false,\"terminated_early\":true,\"_shards\":{\"total\":86,\"successful\":86,\"skipped\":0,\"failed\":0},\"hits\":{\"total\":{\"value\":1489826675,\"relation\":\"eq\"},\"max_score\":1.0,\"hits\":[{\"_index\":\"logs-2019-12-03\",\"_type\":\"log\",\"_id\":\"fEQ1ym4BchgN3v1WBpMd\",\"_score\":1.0,\"_source\":{\"@timestamp\":\"2019-12-03T05:21:42.642+0000\................"
```

However, the same query which is in **--searchBody** is working over kibana with the expected logs starting from **{"@timestamp":"2019-12-03T12:00:03.300+0000"**,
I am not sure what would be missing here. 
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: Thanks @Val 
`version : 7.1.1`

Comment: Can you add the `--debug` flag so we can see what is being run?

Comment: Tried with `--debug`
It generates the same
Thanks, @Val adding that too in description

Comment: Can you see the first query being sent out? i.e. not one of the subsequent scroll requests

Comment: No @Val it just displays logs, adding that too

Comment: You also need to replace `--ignoreType='mapping,settings,template'` (as it is only for multielasticdump) and use `--type=data` instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204554/discussion-between-akshay-vasava-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but better late than never, this may help someone in the future and I'll keep this answer here as a futur reference.

I used Elasticdump `--size` and/or `--searchBody` to slice/filter the data and copy it from one index to another, here are some examples (I'm using Elasticsearch 6.3):

```
# Copy analyzer from my_index to my_index_sample
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index_sample \
  --type=analyzer


# Copy mapping from my_index to my_index_sample
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index_sample \
  --type=mapping


# Copy the first 100 documents from my_index to my_index_sample
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index_sample \
  --type=data \
  --size=100


# Copy documents from my_index to my_index_sample (filtering using query)
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index_sample \
  --type=data \
  --searchBody="{\"query\":{\"term\":{\"username\": \"admin\"}}}" # <--- Your query here


# Copy documents from my_index to my_index_sample (size limit + filtering using query)
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index_sample \
  --type=data \
  --searchBody="{\"query\":{\"term\":{\"username\": \"admin\"}}}" \ # <--- Your query here
  --size=100
```

For more details about elasticdump option, take a look at: https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump#options

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like:

```
./elasticdump --input=http://server:9200 --input-index=metricbeat-7.17.2-2022.06.07-000003 --output=dump/metricbeat-7.17.2-2022.06.07-000003_data.dat --type=data --noRefresh --searchBody="{\"query\":{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\": {\"gte\": \"2021-11-10T19:27:15.000Z\", \"lte\": \"2021-11-11T19:27:15.000Z\"}}}}" --overwrite=true --limit=10000
```